# Angularjs DOM is refreshed but screen is not redrawing. Not sure where to go from here

Tags: angularjs, dom

I am having a very troubling problem where ng-click updates the expected scope variables,  the scope variables appear to change on the DOM ( when viewed via the chrome debugger) but the dom elements that have changed are not redrawn in the browser.  I have noticed across multiple browsers and devices BUT ONLY WHEN THE SCREEN WIDTH IS BELOW 768.  I am using angular version 1.2.6.  Has anyone come across this type of issue??

I have simplified the code to try to isolate and confirm what is happening.  Here is the code in its simplified version:

First the view:

```
<section class="stream-area">
<div class="group">        
    <div class="gw-fixed-top-panel">
        <div  class="group-heading ">
            <div class="panel-title">
                <span class="fleft name" ng-click="usergroup.collapsed=!usergroup.collapsed"> CLICK HERE </span>
                    <a ng-show="usergroup.collapsed" title="Click to edit group" ><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></a>

                    <a ng-hide="usergroup.collapsed" title="Click to edit group" ><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>

                <div> {{usergroup.collapsed}}</div>                           
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

The controller does nothing at this point...

```
'use strict';
(function () {
var groupController = function($scope) {
    $scope.usergroup={};
    $scope.usergroup.collapsed=true;
};
myOverall.myApp.controller('GroupController',['$scope', groupController]);
}());
```

The controller is invoked by via .config:
(function () {
    golfWire.gwWebApp =angular.module('gwWebApp', [
        'ngRoute',
        'ngAnimate',
        'ngResource',
        'ui.bootstrap',
        'firebase',
        'LocalStorageModule',
         'ngGrid'
    ]);

```
myOverall.myApp
    .config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when('/group/view', {
            controller: 'GroupController',
            templateUrl: '/app/views/group.html'
          })
          .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/main'
          });
    /* $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); */
}]);
```

Comment: Do you have separate HTML or (any) scripts for mobile devices in place? Below 768 is a very suspicious number, since it's the most common breakpoint for touch based devices.

Comment: My thoughts exactly.  It appears that it is CSS related.  I didn't realize that CSS could actually prevent the screen from refreshing in certain situations. I am trying to isolate.

Comment: It appears to be related to the element being position:fixed but I don't know why that should matter.

Comment: To make matters worse it only happens on chrome browsers both mobile and desktop versions.

Comment: Appears that this is bug that many have encountered on webkit: http://www.eccesignum.org/blog/solving-display-refreshredrawrepaint-issues-in-webkit-browsers  Unfortunately I believe angular makes this problem worse and none of the suggested techniques to resolve work for me.  Uggh.

Comment: I am abandoning the use of position:fixed.  Since, although its not designed to move,  we can live with it scrolling for now... No other technique could get the browser to fully redraw.  Some result in partial redraws.  If you just resize the browser once ( obviously not possible on mobile ) then it will work fine forever more.

Answer (score 1):

Add this function in your controller

```
$scope.toggleUserGroup = function(){
       $scope.usergroup.collapsed = ! $scope.usergroup.collapsed;
       $scope.$apply();

}
```

Call this function on ng-click. This should get the DOM updated and refreshed.

Reasoning: By calling $apply() you trigger a digest() cycle, which checks for changed expression and repaints the DOM if need be.

Incase this doesn't fix the issue, please provide a plunkr/fiddle. Would be happy to get some working code.

Thanks,

Comment: I'll be the first to admit I'm not an expert on angular but I've always understood that you generally only needed to call $scope.$apply when you are working with data/objects that were loaded outside of the angular process. I believe in the instance of the OP's code that calling $scope.$apply() would result in an angular error stating that a digest cycle is already in process

Answer (score 0):

A slight variation on Eliel's answer in [AngularJS - bind to directive resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170607/angularjs-bind-to-directive-resize/32597385#32597385) worked for me.  In the directive.js:

```
      $scope.onResizeFunction = function() {
      };

      // Call to the function when the page is first loaded
      $scope.onResizeFunction();

      angular.element($(window)).bind('resize', function() {
        $scope.onResizeFunction();
        $scope.$apply();
      });
```

I call

```
    $(window).resize();
```

from within my app.js.  The directive's d3 chart now resizes to fill the container.