# Auto-resize SVG inside AngularJS directive based on container element

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, svg, cross-browser

I am placing an angular directive inside a dynamically-sized element. The directive itself consists of an SVG which is computed based on the element size. I am trying to make the SVG auto-resize and redraw based on the size of the container.

I initially tried something like this:

**my-directive.js**

```
angular
    .module('myModule')
    .directive('myDirective', function () {
        return {
            templateUri: 'path/to/my-directive-template.html',
            ...
        };
    });
```

**my-directive-template.html**

```
<svg style="width: 100%; height: 100%; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%">
    ...
</svg>
```

Note the `style` attributes on that SVG element. This resizes correctly in Chrome, but fails to work in Firefox. Also, I still don't have a hook to recalculate the SVG contents.

I've also tried adding an `onresize` handler to the `element` in the `link` function, However, JQLite supports `onresize` only on the main window. I cannot use `window.onresize`, because my window size does ***not*** change.

I've tried to use the answers here: [AngularJS - bind to directive resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170607/angularjs-bind-to-directive-resize), but they don't give the required results either.

---

In short, here's what I am trying to do:

1. Resize the SVG element inside the directive when the parent element resizes.
2. Re-calculate the SVG contents by calling some handler function when this happens.

I would prefer *not* to add a JQuery dependency at this point in the project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behavior can be achieved using the `viewBox` and `preserveAspectRatio` attributes of the `<svg>` tag.

First, set the [`viewBox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) attribute to a normalized bounding box for your SVG image. Your entire drawing should be scaled to fit inside this view box. For example,

```
viewBox="0 0 100 100"
```

will set up a coordinate system with the origin at (0, 0) and having the dimensions 100 units x 100 units.

Next, set the resizing behavior using the [`preserveAspectRatio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio) attribute.

The first part of the value determines the alignment of the SVG with respect to the parent element. This includes left/right/center horizontal alignment and top/bottom/middle vertical alignment. For example,

```
preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid ..."
```

will align the SVG centrally in its container.

The second part of the value determines how the SVG fills the container. For example,

```
preserveAspectRatio="... meet"
```

will scale the SVG such that it just fits within the container without cropping.

So the complete example becomes:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 64 64" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    ...
</svg>
```

Because the image scales automatically with the container, there is no need to recalculate the positions of the content elements. It is handled automatically by the SVG tag.