# How to make SVG elements inside an AngularJS directive resizable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, svg

In my project, I have a group of svg elements - circles - that are put inside an `<svg>` element (one for all). This `<svg>` element is put inside angular directive.

I want this svg area to be resizable - when a user changes the window size the svg area fits the new size, and all the elements inside it are scaled. I found a very good solution with `<svg>` element properties like `preserveAspectRatio` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146429/auto-resize-svg-inside-angularjs-directive-based-on-container-element) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30717551/how-to-make-svg-responsive). But this works partly for me - I put one of my circles (the blue one) in the center of the svg area. And when I used above mentioned ways for resizing svg, `center circle` was not visible in the center any more. Does someone know how to fix it?

Here is my `index.html`:

```
<div my-content></div>
```

Here is my angular directive:

```
angular
    .module('myApp', [])
    .directive('myContent', function() {
       return {
           restrict: 'EA',
           templateUrl:  'circles.html',
           templateNamespace: 'svg',
           controller: function($scope) {
               $scope.circles = [
                  {"rad": '15', "color": "blue"},
                  {"rad": '25', "color": "green"},
                  {"rad": '30', "color": "red"},
                  {"rad": '35', "color": "brown"}
               ];
               $scope.dimensions = {
                   clientWidth: document.documentElement.clientWidth,
                   clientHeight: document.documentElement.clientHeight
               };
               $scope.renderCircles = function($scope) {
                   $scope.arr = [];
                   $scope.arr.push({
                       cx: $scope.dimensions.clientWidth / 2,
                       cy: $scope.dimensions.clientHeight / 2,
                       r: $scope.circles[0].rad * 2,
                       fill: $scope.circles[0].color
                   });
                   for (var i = 1; i < $scope.circles.length; i++) {
                       $scope.arr.push({
                           cx: $scope.circles[i].rad + i * 3,
                           cy: $scope.circles[i].rad + i * 2,
                           r: $scope.circles[i].rad * 2,
                           fill: $scope.circles[i].color
                       });
                   }
               };
               $scope.renderCircles($scope);
           }
       }
    });
```

Here is the `circles.html`:

```
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"
         viewbox="0 0 500 500" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
         xml:space="preserve">

        <g ng-repeat="circle in arr">
            <circle
                ng-attr-cx="{{ circle.cx }}"
                ng-attr-cy="{{ circle.cy }}"
                ng-attr-r="{{ circle.r }}"
                ng-attr-fill="{{ circle.fill }}">
            </circle>
        </g>
    </svg>
```

I tried different values for `preserveAspectRatio` but no the required result. Maybe someone knows the solution?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share the fiddle for the same?

Comment: @yugantarKumar, please, see my code on [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/glDalOXV9tqTJc9wz8j9?p=preview) as I can't put several html files on fiddle. Thank you!