# AngularJS watch element height change in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-digest

I realize there were several similar questions, I checked them but they don't seem to cover my case.
So I have a fluid flexbox-based layout. Most of the window is used by `container` block, that shrinks when his siblings appear. Basically something like

```
<body>
    <div class="menu"></div>
    <div class="contact"></div>
    <div class="container"></div>
</body>
```

the `container` height is not changed directly, it's recalculated by browser when I toggle other elements, such as `menu`.

I want to watch the `container` height and recalculate some elements in the directive. I watch for its height like this

```
scope.$watch(()=>parentElement.prop('offsetHeight'), resize);
resize=()=>{console.log('resize called');};
```

problem is the resize is triggered only on the **next** digest. so when I toggle the menu for the first time nothing happens, on the second the resize is called but with previous (first call) dimensions and so on.

I realize that it's most likely because the browser resize does not trigger the digest, but the functions that show the menu use $rootScope, so some digest call should occur.

Is there a way to properly watch for element dimensions in this case?

UPD: if I remove the watch filter and listen to every event, I get to resize function when I trigger the menu (obviously it's the rootScope caused call) but the parent element height is still old. Maybe there is a way to defer the watcher? ideally not by timeout but by some event.

Comment: parent element is parentElement=element.parent(), which resolves to the container

Comment: You should probably use https://api.jquery.com/resize/ .

Comment: I'd really like to avoid using jquery, especially for such minor issue

Comment: Did you see this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170607/angularjs-bind-to-directive-resize

Comment: Javascript also has a build in resize event: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp for a no jquery solution.

Comment: I checked it, but watching on whatever parent element property has the same problem (gets called on next digest only) and binding to `resize` does nothing at all