# How to observe when a element size changes in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

What is the best way to do some action when the div in the template changes size? The size of the div changes when the window is resized. With Rxjs Observable/subscribe or are the some other way?

Template:

```
<div #eMainFrame class="main-frame">
   ...
</div>
```

Component:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-box',
   templateUrl: './box.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./box.component.css']
})
export class BoxComponent implements OnInit {
   @ViewChild('eMainFrame') eMainFrame : ElementRef;

   constructor(){}

   ngOnInit(){
     // This shows the elements current size
     console.log(this.eMainFrame.nativeElement.offsetWidth);
   }
}
```

**Updated component** (this example detects when the window size is changed)

```
constructor(ngZone: NgZone) { 

   window.onresize = (e) => {
     ngZone.run(() => {
       clearTimeout(this.timerWindowResize);
       this.timerWindowResize = setTimeout(this._calculateDivSize, 100);
     });
   }
}

_calculateDivSize(){
   console.log(this.eMainFrame.nativeElement.offsetWidth); 
}
```

but this gives me an error:

> EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

Comment: Have you tried `element.resize`? This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170607/angularjs-bind-to-directive-resize

Answer (score 11):

The browser doesn't provide anything, therefore you need to poll the value

`ngDoCheck()` is called when Angular runs change detection. I think this is a good place to do the check:

```
ngDoCheck() {
  console.log(this.eMainFrame.nativeElement.offsetWidth);
}
```

If you only need to check once after component creation, use

```
ngAfterContentInit(){
  // This shows the elements current size
  console.log(this.eMainFrame.nativeElement.offsetWidth);
}
```

Comment: The ngDoCheck works but the ngDoCheck() will be called a lot of times.

Comment: Every time change detection runs. It depends on your exact requirements and if there is an event that you can utilize for better timing when to read the size.